# Using min() in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sorting, select

My sql knowledge is not that good and after 2 hours of brainstorm i decided to ask my fellow friends in here.

Here is my problem, i am developing a travel website. There are regions and prices table. structure is basicly like this.

```
regions             region_contents         prices
-------             ----------------        --------
regionId            regionId                priceId
regionName          hotelId                 hotelId
someMoreFields      someMoreFields          price
                                            beginDate
                                            endDate
                                            someMoreFields
```

What i want out of this data is

```
  +-----------------+-------------+-------------------------+
  |        hotelId  |  hotelName  |  min price for this Id  |
  +-----------------+-------------+-------------------------+
  |        hotelId  |  hotelName  |  min price for this Id  |
  +-----------------+-------------+-------------------------+
  |        hotelId  |  hotelName  |  min price for this Id  |
  +-----------------+-------------+-------------------------+
  |        hotelId  |  hotelName  |  min price for this Id  |
  +-----------------+-------------+-------------------------+
```

I query for all the hotels in spesific region ordered by min price for each hotel and the endDate of price for each hotel should be later than NOW().

Thanks in advance.
Also apoligies for bad grammar.

Comment: where exactly does date come in the picture? Do you query for a date range and then get the minimum price for that range?

Comment: No, i query for all the hotels in spesific region ordered by min price for each hptel and the endDate of price for each hotel should be later than NOW(). Sorry should have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should be what you need:

```
SELECT hotel_id, hotel_name, MIN(price)
FROM region
JOIN region_contents 
   ON regionName = <reqdname> AND region.regionID = region_contents.regionID
JOIN prices 
   ON region_contents.hotel_id = prices_hotel_id
WHERE end_date > NOW()
GROUP BY hotel_id
ORDER BY MIN(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

I asume that you need data from all your tables, which is a `JOIN` followed by a `GROUP BY` to utilize the `MIN()` function:

```
SELECT rc.hotelId, rc.hotelName, MIN(p.price) FROM regions r
LEFT JOIN region_contents rc ON r.regionId = rc.regionId
LEFT JOIN prices p ON p.hotelId = rc.hotelID
GROUP BY rc.hotelId
```

[MySQL manual on GROUP BY-agregated functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min)

Comment: You're going to get an error on hotelName as it's not contained in the GROUP BY clause or an aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something but this seems straightforward...

```
SELECT
 hotelId,
 hotelName,
 MIN(price)
FROM
 region_contents
INNER JOIN
 prices
ON
 region_contents.hotel_id = prices.hotel_id
GROUP BY
 hotelId,
 hotelName
ORDER BY
 MIN(price)
```